# Rails bundle install password required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundle, vendor

Somebody tried to help me in my app rails , he removed rbenv and other stuff i don't remind. And now when I'm doing bundle install i must enter my laptop password. Before it was not required.

the error messsage is :

"
Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

```
  bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password: "

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You are using system ruby, which is installed not only for your user, but system-wide. That's why you need `sudo` and password.

Just install rbenv or rvm and everything will be back as it was

Comment: i have rbenv installed, when i type `gem env home` it prints out `/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0`, but still, when i run `bundle` it asks me for a password. Any thoughts?

Comment: what does `which bundle` say?

Comment: it says `/usr/local/bin/bundle`

Comment: this is the reason. you're still using the system-wide bundler gem. try `gem install bundler`

Comment: thanks! that helped, well, actually i tried that before.. but now i also tried `sudo gem uninstall bundler`, `gem uninstall bundler`, `gem cleanup bundler`; then it finally worked :)

Comment: Getting the follow error, following instructions: 

gem install bundler
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Fetching bundler-2.2.26.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
$ sudo asdf uninstall ruby 2.6.5
$ asdf install ruby 2.6.5
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle
```

In some moment at Ruby installation I had used `sudo`, so I needed to reinstall.